# Need suggestions on improving a very simple c# server restarter

Tags: c#, winforms

Recently I had an idea for a simple auto restarter for my server exe.

Basically all it does is

- Checks if there is a process named `WerFault` running
- If there is that means the server has crashed, so it closes both the server and `WerFault`
- After that opens the server again.
- The second thing it checks for is if the `wServer` is even running, if not it starts it up.

This all is within a  timer with a delay of 10 seconds.

However I am very sure that there is a much more efficient way of doing this.  I learned C# on my own (have not read a single book, all I know was acquired thru self learning + Google).

Also the reason why I want the server to be open 24/7 is because it will run on a vps.

Note: This is a windows forms application.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process[] prs = Process.GetProcesses(); 
            foreach (Process pr in prs)
            {
                if (pr.ProcessName == "WerFault") 
                {
                    pr.Kill(); 

                    if (pr.ProcessName == "wServer") 
                    {
                        pr.Kill(); 
                        Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Arturs\Dropbox\ROTMGServer-master\bin\Debug\wServer\wServer.exe"); 
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }

            if (pr.ProcessName == "wServer")
            {
                return;
            }

            Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Arturs\Dropbox\ROTMGServer-master\bin\Debug\wServer\wServer.exe");                
            return;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your usage of parenthesis is wierd. You use too many.

Comment: instead of writing a program to monitor your service, why dont you use Microsoft utilities to do the job, MOM, or perhaps if you have installed this as a service, you could program this to restart itself with a delay after it crashed. One less tool in your toolbox - or you may end up writing another tool to monitor the monitor. :)

Answer (score 0):

You've written:

```
if (pr.ProcessName == "WerFault") 
{
   pr.Kill(); 
   {
       if (pr.ProcessName == "wServer") 
       {
           // ...
```

It is unlikely that there will ever be a process `pr` whose `ProcessName` is both the string `"WerFault"` *and* the string `"wServer"`.

Perhaps you want to move the second `if` *outside* of the first one.